# MVC5 Controller: Return list of all Paid MemberOrgs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 respective tables in my MVC5 Application involving Member Dues:

```
[MemberDues] -- [Id], [Year], [Display], [Amount]

[MemberDuesReceived] -- [Id], [MemberDuesId], [MemberOrgId], [PaidByUserId], [TransactionId], [Paid], [DatePaid], [PaymentMethod], [PayPalPaymentId], [PayPalPayerId], [PayPalPaymentState]
```

For the `MemberDuesManageController` I am trying to create a `ViewDuesPaidMembers()` method where I return a list of all the MemberOrgs who have paid their dues. Now, I can get the current `MemberDues.[Id]` by passing my Model Id from a button on my Index View, and searching the database: `MemberDues memberDues = await db.MemberDues.FindAsync(id);`

What I'm unsure of is how I use this `MemberDues.[Id]`  to search the `MemberDuesReceived` table and return a list of all the `MemberDuesReceived.[MemberOrgId]` with a `[Paid]` value of `True` within my ActionResult.

Below is what I have thus far. Can anyone provide an example of how I can return the appropriate list of MemberOrgs from the other table?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ViewDuesPaidMembers(int id)
        {
            MemberDues memberDues = await db.MemberDues.FindAsync(id);
            return null;
        }
```

**EDIT**:

Taking into account Jonesy's suggestion I now have:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> DuesPaidMembers(int id)
        {
            MemberDues memberDues = await db.MemberDues.FindAsync(id);
            var duesPaidList = db.MemberDuesReceived.Where(mdr => mdr.MemberDuesId == id && mdr.Paid).ToList();
            return View(duesPaidList);
        }
```

What I'm trying to figure out now is how to set up my Button  so that it will use the new controller method `DuesPaidMembers()` and redirect to view `DuesPaidMember.cshtml` to display my list of paid MemberOrgs:

```
<a href="MembersDuesManage/DuesPaidMembers/@item.Id" class="btn btn-default btn-sm noDecoration"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>  View Paid</a>
```

Currently my button takes me to `http://localhost:15160/Admin/MembersDuesManage/DuesPaidMembers/1`, with a message of: `"The resource cannot be found."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Find` uses the primary key to locate a single record.  You want to use `Where` on your foreign key table:

```
var duesList = db.MemberDuesReceived
                   .Where(mdr => mdr.MemberDuesId == id && mdr.Paid)
                   .ToList();
```

assuming `Paid` is a bool value.

If you're wanting just a List of `MemberOrgId` you'd add a Select statement:

```
var idList = db.MemberDuesReceived
                  .Where(mdr => mdr.MemberDuesId == id && mdr.Paid)
                  .Select(mdr => mdr.MemberOrgId) 
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Jonesy! Seems like every time I start this project and get a small hang of things I then get pulled away to another and forget basic stuff like this. I'm returning my list to View, but not quite sure how to set up my button to redirect to my new View with the List(): `<a href="MembersDuesManage/DuesPaidMembers/@item.Id" class="btn btn-default btn-sm noDecoration"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>  Paid</a>` to redirect to my `DuesPaidMembers.cshtml` I created under `MemberDuesManage` folder in `Views`.

Comment: Well it looks like your action is `ViewDuesPaidMembers` so make sure you call it by the correct name.  Other than that I'd need more information.  It's probably worth opening a different question if you can't resolve it.

Comment: Ok, I added some more information in my Edit. If you don't spot anything immediately I'll open up a new quesiton.

Comment: `/Admin/MembersDuesManage/DuesPaidMembers/` seems unusual, unless you've altered your routing significantly.  Normally it's `controller/action/id`

Comment: Hmm... yea, it's still the same `controller/action/id` routing, except in this instance I have created a new `Area` (http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html) within my application called `Admin`. I have `MemberDuesManageController` under my `Admin` area `Controllers`, and the `DuesPaidMembers` action within that controller, where I get my List() and attempt to return to `Admin/Views/MemberDuesManage/DuesPaidMembers.cshtml`. Does that provoke any thoughts?